# Pandas DataFrame: update all values in all columns, based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Check all column's values. If the value is greater than **100,000**:

-> Subtract **4294967295** and then add **1** to it.

I did it, but for one column like this:

`df.loc[df['12:00AM'] > 100000, '12:00AM'] = (4294967295 - df.loc[df['12:00AM'] > 100000, '12:00AM']) +1`

I want to apply this code for all columns.

Comment: You could use a loop.

Comment: `df[df > 100000] -= 4294967294`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it like this: where : **A-B = -B+A**

```
df[df> 100000] = -1*df[df> 100000] + 4294967295+1
```